# Символьный массив и перевод из двоичной системы в 10-ую

Tags: c++, c

Есть символьный массив, в которые вводятся числа 0 и 1. Нужно с помощью функции перевести элементы символьного массива из двоичной системы счисления в 10-ную.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>

int sys2to10(char str);

int main() {


    int result = sys2to10(str);
    printf("Введите последовательность:");
    char str[10] = {0};
    scanf("%6s", str);
    printf("%d", result);


    return (0);
}

int sys2to10(char str) {
    int psum = 0;
    for(int i = 6; i > 0; i --) {
        psum += (int str[i] * (pow(2, i-1)));
    }
    return (psum);
}
```

Но компилятор ругается, не могу понять в чём ошибка.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про самые основы работы с функциями. Вот это: `int result = sys2to10;` - бессмыслица...

Comment: А как правильнее это всё реализовать? Статьи, которые я читал про пользовательские функции в Си, говорилось о том, что функция вызывается следующим образом: переменная = ИмяФункции;

Comment: Ну-ка покажите мне ссылку на статью, которая предлагает так вызывать функции. После имени функции должны быть скобки с аргументами.

Comment: https://prog-cpp.ru/c-functions/ Или я не так понял, или в статье ошибка.

Comment: @David, так вот же Переменная = ИмяФункции(СписокФактическихАргументов);

Comment: А вас не смущает, что функции `printf` `scanf` `pow` вы вызваете по-другому?

Comment: Да, вижу моя ошибка. Исправил это, но от этого программа всё равно не стала рабочей.

Comment: @VTT В каком смысле я вызываю по другому?

Comment: После правки - все еще неправильно. В скобках должны быть не типы, а имена переменных.

Comment: *"В каком смысле я вызываю по другому?"* `printf` `scanf` `pow` - такие же функции, как и `sys2to10`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, я исправил. Тогда возникает вопрос, имена всех переменных которые используются в этой функции или лишь имя входной переменной, то есть str в данном случае?

Comment: Будет проще, если вы почитаете какую-нибудь хорошую книгу или туториал... Разжевывать вам здесь все в подробностях - долго, и книга справилась бы с этим лучше.

Comment: сталь как без вы  знаний  закаляется,  не   8 сделать. Так выглядит ваша программа. Вы же не догадались, что я хотел написать:  без знаний как закаляется сталь, инструмент не сделаешь

Comment: Если компилятор ругается, то чтобы понять в чем ошибка, нужно прочитать ругань компилятора. Если все равно непонятно, то нужно вставить сообщение компилятора в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ощущение, что вы начитались какой-то фантастики о путешествиях во времени - сначала вычисляете, потом спрашиваете, что вычислять...

Сначала вычисляем неизвестно что (`str` - неизвестно!) "Шофер, домой! - а где вы живете? - не твое дело!"...

```
int result = sys2to10(str);
```

Потом просим  ввести последовательность

```
printf("Введите последовательность:");
```

Наконец, объявляем `str` и читаем...

```
char str[10] = {0};
scanf("%6s", str);
```

И выводим нечто, вычисленное не пойми из чего...

```
printf("%d", result);
```

Вобщем, вот ваш код. Без проверок и защит от дурака.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>

int sys2to10(char * str);

int main()
{
    char str[10] = {0};
    printf("Введите последовательность: ");
    scanf("%6s", str);
    int result = sys2to10(str);
    printf("%d", result);
}

int sys2to10(char * str)
{
    int psum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        psum = psum*2 + (str[i] - '0');
    return psum;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает. Можете пожалуйста еще объяснит эту строчку: psum = psum*2 + (str[i] - '0'); И в какой части кода тут возведение в степень ?

Comment: *"Зачем нам кузнец? я не лошадь"* (с) :) Зачем нам возводить в степень? Что такое, скажем, число 12345? Это просто (((1*10+2)*10+3)*10+4)*10+5... Нигде не вычисляем 10 в степени - просто не нужно. Точно так же я подошел и тут - слева направо, он наиболее значащей цифры к меньшей, множа на основание системы счисления и прибавляя очередную цифру...

Comment: А что значит str[i] - '0' ?

Comment: А в `str[i]` - *символ*, а не число. Вычитание `'0'` превращает *символ* 0 в *число* 0 (и то же - для единиц).

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вычитание из символа - '0' превращает данный символ в число ? или если мне надо символ 9 превратить в цифру 9, то надо уже вычитать '9' ?

Comment: Нет, именно `'0'`. Ну сами представьте - у числа (от 0 до 9) код символа - `'0'+число` - они идут подряд... `символ числа == '0'+число`

Comment: Понял, очень полезная информация, не знал об этом прежде. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Данное объявление функции

```
int sys2to10(char str);
```

является некорректным, так как в функцию передается строка, а не символ.

Поэтому функцию следует объявить как

```
int sys2to10( const char *str );
```

В функции используется, не понятно, откуда взявшееся магическое число `6`:

```
for(int i = 6; i > 0; i --) {
           ^^^
```

Данное выражение

```
psum += (int str[i] * (pow(2, i-1)));
```

синтаксически неверное,

В функции `main` вы сначала должны объявить и инициализировать символьный массив `str` и лишь затем вызывать функцию

```
int result = sys2to10(str);
```

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано ниже в демонстрационной программе, написанной на C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sys2to10( const char *s )
{
    const int Base =  2;

    int result = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        result = Base * result + ( *s - '0' ); 
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "1101";

    printf( "%d\n", sys2to10( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```